# How to use javascript in my code using Appium library

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying automate Mobile application using Appium Library in Robot Framework. Can anybody help me how to use java script for clicking on button.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there anything you tried? It would be great to know what error are you facing. :)

Comment: @TobiasWilfert 1-Wait Until Element Is Visible
2-click element

Comment: @LubosJerabek 
the click passes correctly in the report but it does not click on the button in device

Comment: I have to do a test in the mobile application and check in another web application to open the chrome browser in the device but the problem my script is correct and he has to click on the button but it does not redirect to the page of acceuile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Execute%20Script

Then you should be able to pass your JavaScript to this function, e.g.

```
Execute Script    document.getElementById("elementId").click()
```

Comment: i have installed the last version of Appiumlibrary  and the keyword not exist in this version i dont know why

Comment: Unknown keyword 'Execute Script'  even the error message displayed it works thank you

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: Method is not implemented I am getting this error and script is failing

Comment: I am just running console log. like this : Execute Script   console.log('hello') I also tried accessing DOM element but there is same error.

Comment: I rechecked my DOM ID and they are correct.  Here you can check what exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052275/set-value-of-ion-range-slider-to-specific-value

Comment: Do you think there is version issue? I am on appium library 1.17.0

Comment: Probably worth raising a new question here. I'm not an Appium Library expert so unable to help that well.